# Python Anaconda installation problem on ubuntu

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed anaconda3 on ubuntu 19.10 by using this guide
 https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/

But after finishing the installation when it asks

`Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda3 install location to PATH in your /home/username/.bashrc ? [yes|no]`

It typed 'no'. And after that, I can't figure out how to run conda or from where to launch it?

Comment: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/#open-nav-lin

Comment: `conda activate base`

Comment: @sahasrara62 What that command do?

Comment: will activate conda default python environment